# ¿Cómo asignar el return code en aplicación de linea de comandos dependiendo del resultado de una función?

Tags: c#

Tengo una aplicación de línea de comandos la cual ejecuta una función de una DLL, la función me puede regresar distintos códigos. Me gustaría utilizar esos códigos para asignar el *return code* del exe.

Este es mi código:

```
namespace SendImg
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            String IP = args[0];
            String PUERTO = args[1];
            String RUTA = args[2];
            String TIPO = args[3];

            Conexion Cte = new Conexion();
            Socket Cliente_bascula = Cte.conectar(IP, Int32.Parse(PUERTO));

            if (Cliente_bascula != null && Cliente_bascula.Connected == true)
            {
                CommandTorrey myobj = new CommandTorrey();
                int iRtaFunct = myobj.TORREYSendImagesToScale(IP, RUTA, TIPO, Cliente_bascula); 

                if (iRtaFunct == 0)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("La imagen se envio correctamente");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error en la transferencia de la imagen: " + iRtaFunct.ToString());

                }

                Cte.desconectar(ref Cliente_bascula);
            }
            else
            {

                Console.WriteLine("No se pudo conectar a la bascula");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

y quiero devoler el valor entero de `iRtaFunct` como código de salida de esta aplicación.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplemente haz que el método `Main` devuelva un `int` con el código de error  en lugar de `void`.

```
namespace SendImg
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ...

            if (Cliente_bascula != null && Cliente_bascula.Connected == true)
            {
                CommandTorrey myobj = new CommandTorrey();
                int iRtaFunct = myobj.TORREYSendImagesToScale(IP, RUTA, TIPO, Cliente_bascula); 

                // ...

                return iRtaFunct;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No se pudo conectar a la bascula");
                return -1; // O algún otro código de error que desees. 
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,